# #temp table equivalent in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Sql Server, we can create temp table in sql editor like :

```
select * into #temp_sales_data from sales_data; -- this will create a temp table and insert data.
```

Please let us know what is the equivalent option in Postgres.

Comment: In case you couldn't find the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/search/?u=%2Fdocs%2F14%2F&q=temp+table

Comment: Not sure why people downvote this, this is causing SO to be less popular, just about every question matters -- be nice and just answer. This helped me, thank you Prasanna Kumar for asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create one using `create temp table`

```
create temp table temp_sales_data
as
select *
from sales_data;
```